# How to change NSAttributedString font size from HTML data - swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I receive a html string, and I convert it successfully.
The html string shows on my view, but I can't change it font size.
I use following code in NSMutableAttributedString options:

> NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)

this is my code:

```
extension String{
func convertHtml() -> NSMutableAttributedString{
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }
    do{
        return try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                                      options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,
                                          NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
    }catch{
        return NSMutableAttributedString()
    }
}
}


textLabel.attributedText = message.content.convertHtml()
```

HTML string like this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com.tw">https://www.google.com.tw </a>
<a href="myAppName://app/user/aa3b77411825b88b318d77gg">@Tim </a><a href="https://www.google.com.tw">https://www.google.com.tw </a>
<a href="myAppName://app/user/aa3b77411825b88b318d77gg">@Tim </a>Hello Tim
```

Now Look(I want to change text size):
 
[image]

Comment: FYI - you are asking two completely unrelated questions. Focus this one on the font issue.

Comment: Okay, I change the question title.

Comment: @tolerate＿Me_Thx are you asking for change html font size ? right ?

Comment: @ravi.p Yes, I am.

Comment: @tolerate＿Me_Thx here is the answer                                              let strFontSizeHtml = "<body style=\"font-size: \(fontSizeHERE)px;\">\(YOURHTMLTEXT ?? "")</body>"
                        
       webViewHtmlText.loadHTMLString(strFontSizeHtml, baseURL: nil)

Comment: @tolerate＿Me_Thx have you tried ??